# Is there any solution for unable to load DLL“ArcGISVersion.dll”?

Tags: c#, arcgis, esri

I have tried set the build platform to x86, But still this error.
And It works on my PC but others.

[image: here's the error screenshot]

Comment: is the `dll` in particular exists? if yes, is it added as reference manually? is it on system's `path` on the working machine?

Comment: Seems fairly unambiguous... the DLL is not available on the machine you're trying to run the program on, or it isn't somewhere it can be found. Either you need to install the appropriate library or tools that provide arcgisversion.dll (and possibly other arcgis dlls, too) or you need make sure that those DLLs are on your path or in the directory the application's executable is.